# Are there limits on one's entitlement to have overnight guests as an assured shorthold tenant?

Tags: england-and-wales, tenancy-rules

Whether in shared accommodation (ie, a house in multiple occupation) or as a sole occupant, can one be restricted on how many nights a month one shares one's room with another person?

Comment: Does the tenancy agreement say anything relevant?

Comment: Related, but not necessarily a duplicate: [How long can someone sleep over at someone else's rented accommodation?](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/73243/35069)

Comment: Some useful answers to this similar Quora question: https://www.quora.com/Can-my-landlord-stop-me-from-having-guests-UK